# ¿Cómo configurar Emacs para trabajar con PHP?

Tags: php, emacs

¿Qué paquetes debo instalar en Emacs para escribir código con formato PHP?

Me refiero a tener syntax highlight, auto completado, corrección de errores. En resumen, paquetes que faciliten el desarrollo de aplicaciones PHP en Emacs.

Comment: por ejemplo: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PhpMode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Emacs` tiene un `php-mode`. Con tu fichero abierto:

```
M-x php-mode
```

Y el buffer actual se pondrá en modo PHP.

Si quieres que los ficheros PHP se abran directamente en el modo PHP, añade, en tu `~/.emacs`:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.php\\'" . php-mode))
```

Tendrás *syntax-highlighting* al menos, aunque no sé qué otras características tendrá el PHP mode dado que no programo mucho en PHP.

Necesitas tener instalado el paquete `php-elisp` para que tengas modo PHP en Emacs. Para ver si ya lo tienes instalado:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep "php"
```

Si en la lista ves un paquete llamado `php-elisp`, y aparece como instalado, ya está. Si no:

```
sudo apt-get install php-elisp
```

Answer (score 0):

También dispones de spacemacs (http://spacemacs.org) que te va a proporcionar un buen conjunto de paquetes que te facilitaran tu labor a la hora de programar, autocompletar, etc.

Lo digo porque sin mucho esfuerzo tienes un entorno emacs bastante potente. Aunque para mi gusto lo mejor es adecuarte tu entorno, instalar los paquetes, los modos, los temas... que te gusten y vayas a usar y punto. Aunque estuve bastante tiempo usando spacemacs y muy contento, el único problema es que tienes muchos paquetes y funcionalidades que no usas.